# error when i change key field to any value other than " my-add-on" in atlassian-connect json file

Tags: json, cloud, jira, confluence

I am developing an addon on Confluence cloud and I can upload this addon in the confluence cloud instance  successfully and everything going well BUT when I modify the field `key` in Json file (`atlassian-connect.json`) which is the descriptor of my add-on like this:

```
From <<"key": "my-add-on",>> TO << "key": "any_caracter",>>
```

I get the following error message:

> The add-on host returned HTTP response code 401 when we tried to
>   contact it during installation. Please try again later or contact the
>   add-on vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Yooopi i found the solution

delete the "store.db" file which exist on the same directory of "app.js" and then it will be generated automatically again.

have nice day Geeks ^^